# Error occured while comping cocos2dx 3.13.1

Tags: cocos2d-x

I have an old project in cocos2dx 3.13.1. I have made some changes in the game last week. After making some changes i compiled it for ios from xcode and it works well, but while trying to compile in android using **cocos compile -p android --android-studio** command in terminal, i faced following error. I have used android-ndk-r14b, apache-ant-1.10.1 and Android SDK Tools Version 26.0.2

```
Android NDK: WARNING: Unsupported source file extensions in jni/Android.mk for module cocos2dcpp_shared    
Android NDK:   ../../../Classes/NewsLayer    
Android NDK: ERROR:/Users/pradipbhattarai/Desktop/Testing/cocos2d/external/freetype2/prebuilt/android/Android.mk:cocos_freetype2_static: LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file    
Android NDK: Check that /Users/pradipbhattarai/Desktop/Testing/cocos2d/external/freetype2/prebuilt/android/x86_64/libfreetype.a exists  or that its path is correct   
make: Entering directory `/Users/pradipbhattarai/Desktop/Testing/proj.android-studio/app'
/Users/pradipbhattarai/development/java/android-ndk-r14b/build/core/prebuilt-library.mk:45: *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
make: Leaving directory `/Users/pradipbhattarai/Desktop/Testing/proj.android-studio/app'
Error running command, return code: 2.
```

any help will be highly appreciable.

Comment: You might be missing dependencies. Have a look at the bottom of this thread
https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/issues/15713

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue, but i just forgot to post my solution. I think it will be solution to other developers who are facing same problem. The problem was with the .d files. After removing the previous .d files, the problem was solved.
 Go to proj.android-studio/app/obj/local and remove the armeabi directory. It worked for me.
Reference Link: https://sysprogs.com/w/forums/topic/unable-to-compile-cpufeatures-library-on-android/

Answer (score 0):

look at the error:-

Android NDK: ERROR:/Users/pradipbhattarai/Desktop/Testing/cocos2d/external/freetype2/prebuilt/android/Android.mk:cocos_freetype2_static: LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file

One of the reason is that you have entry of a class file in Android.mk file , that you have deleted from Class folder. Suppose you have entry of 'HelloWorldScene.cpp'in Android.mk but you have already deleted this filr from Class folder.
Please check that